# Merging a folder in SVN records only the folder in the log, and not the files inside it

Tags: sql-server, svn, merge, continuous-integration

The scenario is as follows.

We're running a CI server which scans a repository for any .sql changes, then executes them against a target database.

Currently it's failing because SVN is not recording file changes within a folder (that has been merged from a branch). Merge info was commit too.

Example:

- Developer branches "/Trunk" to "/Branches/CR1"
- Developer adds a new folder "CR1/Scripts"
- Developer adds two new files "Scripts/Script1.sql" and "Scripts/Script2.sql"
- Developer commits the folder and files together
- Developer merges from CR1 to Trunk, commit dialog displays status "Normal"

[image: Commit Dialog showing a status of "Normal"]

- CI server detects no changes
- Developer examines the log and sees no mention of Script1.sql or Script2.sql

[image: Commit Log showing no changed scripts]

All this is displayed via TortoiseSVN on Windows, the CI Server is using SharpSvn .NET library.

Any help figuring out how to get the *.sql files to show up would very much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nearing a year, and during this time we've used a workaround to find the missing files. Using the CLI command `svn log -v` we scanned for any directory with the `COPY-FROM-PATH` text and listed the contents from that directory on disk rather than SVN.

Whilst this does provide us with a full list of files in that folder, we should really be able to get this info remotely without checking out a copy of the repository. When a co-worker also encountered this issue recently they found the the answer courtesy of the IRC channel #svn on freenode.

Using the CLI command `svn diff <url>[old rev] <url>[new rev] --summarize` you get a difference between the revisions which thanks to the `--summarize` flag displays all the files and which finally answered the original question.